# How to get the last variable value in the end of class?

Tags: java, class, variables

How to access to the last value of the variable from another class? The program runs in 30 seconds and the end of 30 seconds, It prints variables.

**Game class**:

```
public class Game {
    public int true_num = 0, false_num = 0;

    public Game() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        new TimerDemo(30);
        while (true) {
            play(); // true_num/false_num are changed in this method.
        }

    }
}
```

**TimerDemo class**:

```
public class TimerDemo {
        Toolkit toolkit;

    Timer timer;

    public TimerDemo(int seconds) {
        toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds * 1000);
    }

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Time's up!");

            JLabel lb = new JLabel("true_num = " + true_num
                    + " and " + "false_num = " + false_num);
            lb.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
            UIManager.put("OptionPane.minimumSize", new Dimension(150, 90));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lb, "aaa", 1);

            toolkit.beep();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

How to access the last value of the variables in the play function in Game class? call class is caused `play function` runs again that should not.

Comment: Give TimerDemo a reference to the Game instance e.g. via the constructor `new TimerDemo(30, this);` Also `true_num` should technically be `volatile` if you want to guarantee the timer task can read the actual value

Comment: @zapal, I did and it worked: `private final Game get_val;

        private RemindTask(Game1 aThis) {
            get_val = aThis;
        }` and `get_val.true_num`. but Game runs again after end of 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without reference from Game, I adding Game.total and defined [volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/do-you-ever-use-the-volatile-keyword-in-java) total in Game.

In TimerDemo:

```
public void run() {
     System.out.println("Time's up! Total = " + Game.total + "true_num =" + Game.true_num + "false_num =" + Game.false_num);
}
```

In Game:

```
public static volatile int true_num = 0, false_num = 0, total = 0;
```